# Maintaining indexes on lists

Tags: python, database, sorting, indexing, python-2.7

How should I implement very fast lookups of items in a collection?

```
class Person(object):
    __all__ = dict()

    def __init__(self, _id, name, age):
        self._id = _id
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.__class__.__all__[_id] = self
```

Suppose I wish to get the five oldest people. If `len(Person.__all__)` is quite large, and I need to do this operation frequently, what is the best practice? Currently my code takes about 4hrs to run, and I haven't even fed the whole dataset in yet.

My current thinking is that I could use a database to maintain indexes, but my feeling is that this would be slower than keeping all objects in ram. (I can comfortably fit every object in ram).

*Or*, I could have some sort of index based on an auto-sorted list, within Python. So, when I needed to look up people of a certain age, I would query that list, to find ids, then use `Person.__all__` to get the object itself.

What would be the best option?

Comment: Four hours? You must have a **lot** of persons in your DB… Seriously, show us your code.

Comment: Just go with a database. (`SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 5`)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `__*__` is reserved, use `__all` if you want to make a private property.

Comment: What are the double underscores after `all` for?

Comment: @gnibbler `__*__` methods and properties are for class costumization, overriding operators, etc. `__*` are private properties, the interpreter rename those properties so your code fail to access it *directly*.

Comment: @KurzedMetal, I know how double underscores work, but as you already commented, the ones _after_ `__all` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @plaes, you should make that comment into an answer so I can upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an in memory database with sqlite. It's easy to move the db to disk later on if you need to

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is the Python version of a hash table, which guarantees (on average) fast lookups. It does *not* guarantee fast "finding the least *k* elements" -- indeed, that will be slow, because you will need to look through every single person in the dict.

Instead, you want to store the people in a *sorted* data structure, since then you can just look at the first (or maybe last) five entries to find the oldest people.

Python doesn't have a built-in data structure like that, but there is a well-used and well-tested package called [`blist`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist) which offers a `sorteddict`. You want to use one of them.